# How do I set the number of concurrent requests when building an OkHttpClient?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

## Background

I am building a Retrofit client.  As part of this client, I am also building an OkHttpClient within it.  Below is the code I am speaking of:

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/<secret-key>/";
public static final OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().dispatcher()

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static DarkSkyEndpoints getClient() {

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .client(httpClient.build())
               .build();
    }

    DarkSkyEndpoints endpoints = retrofit.create(DarkSkyEndpoints.class);
    return endpoints;
}
```

## What I want

I want to build an OkHttpClient that only allows 1 concurrent thread at a time.

## What I know

1. I know there is a method called [dispatcher()](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#dispatcher-okhttp3.Dispatcher-) that can be chained next to an OkHttpClient.Builder() as shown above.
2. I know that the [Dispatcher](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Dispatcher.html) class has a method [setMaxRequests()](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Dispatcher.html#setMaxRequests-int-) that accomplishes exactly what I want to do.

## What I don't know

How do I set the maximum number of concurrent threads when building an OkHttpClient for Retrofit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need create instance of `Dispatcher` class and pass it to `dispatcher()` method. Try something like this:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
dispatcher.setMaxRequests(MAX_REQUESTS_NUMBER);
public static final OkHttpClient httpClient = new 
OkHttpClient.Builder().dispatcher(dispatcher).build();
....
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient)
            .build();
```